# combineLatest on array in RxSwift

Tags: swift, reactive-programming

The code below was demonstrated by Ash Furrow during an FRP presentation and using RxSwift.  Unfortunately the "combineLatest" operator of RxSwift only allows for up to 10 observables. I am looking for a workaround to get the same result but on an array of observables instead.

Any ideas?

```
class SignupDemoViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var emailAddressTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var signupButton: UIButton!

  let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let emailIsValid = emailAddressTextField.rx_text >- map (isEmail)
    let passwordIsValid = passwordTextField.rx_text >- map (isPassword)

    combineLatest(emailIsValid, passwordIsValid)
        >- and
        >- signupButton.rx_subscribeEnabledTo
        >- disposeBag.addDisposable

    signupButton.rx_tap
        >- signup
        >- display
        >- disposeBag.addDisposable
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array versions of combineLatest and zip are supported from version of RxSwift-2.0-alpha.1 forward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's an example:

`let arr = [Observable<Bool>]()

arr.combineLatest { (items: [Bool]) -> Bool in !items.contains(false) }`

It can combine to any type, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

It's now `Observable.combineLatest(array)` instead of `array.combineLatest`.